# python regex not matching whitespace inside capture group

Tags: python, regex, whitespace, capture-group

```
date_re = re.compile(r'^stuff (\d\d-\d\d\s)')
date_re.search('stuff 10-18 16:51').group(1)
```

Does not match because of the `\s`. If I remove the whitespace symbol the group will find the xx-xx digit pattern fine. What am I doing wrong with the space in the regex?

My full code:

```
>>> print t
stuff 11-16 12:10, Size 1.64 GiB, ULed by 
>>>date_long_re = re.compile(r'^stuff (\d\d-\d\d\s\d\d\d\d)')
>>>size_re = re.compile(r'Size \d+[.\d*]?')
>>>date_re = re.compile(r'^stuff (\d\d-\d\d\s)')
>>>date_re.search(t).group(1)

AttributeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-18bd3a48937c> in <module>()
      3 size_re = re.compile(r'Size \d+[.\d*]?')
      4 date_re = re.compile(r'^stuff(\d\d-\d\d\s)')
----> 5 date_re.search(t).group(1)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: [I cannot repro](https://ideone.com/AUqNcV).

Comment: What is in `stuff` ?

Comment: stuff is a string literal. I too cannot reproduce in that web intrepreter, neither on my local interpreter. I am using the anaconda jupyter distribution and it's only happening in this but I cannot get around it....

Comment: it will also not reproduce in a new jupyter notebook. Puzzling!

Comment: I have updated with the trace

Comment: i changed the name of the re variable and it now works...

Comment: on a duplicate of the original jupyter notebook. The original is still messed up, even though I have changed variable names several times.

Answer (score -2):

```
import unicodedata

t= unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", t)
```

...there was an irate `\xa0` in the unicode string.